# How to find out which wcf services are hosted

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

How can I find out what wcf services are currently hosted, including information like the base address? (with C#)

hosted on the local machine (with Visual Studio or IIS)

Comment: Hosted where?  Using what kind of transport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of different ways to host wcf components - IIS, Windows Services, console apps, etc etc.  I don't think there's a programmatic way to discover and iterate over them all.