# How to see all currently hosted services by WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service, hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find out which wcf services are hosted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161253/how-to-find-out-which-wcf-services-are-hosted)

Hello everyone.
I am developing some wcf services to do something... no need to bother you with other details...

Sometimes, especially with those services using `basicHttpBinding`, there are services that are still hosted even when my applications quit.

However, not just for the reason I mentioned before, it could be very useful to have a tool that lists, everytime it is executed, the services currently being hosted by .NET.

How can I deal with this? Thankyou